# Volatility forecast on SPX option expiration day

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, forecasting, spx, expiration

I am looking for methods and papers on forecasting SPX option at-the-money implied volatility or realized volatility within its expiration day. What are some stylized facts and forecasting methods?